# Average values across multiple files

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script to average several identically formatted files with names `file1`, `file2`, `file3` and so on.

In each file, the data is in a table of a format like for example 4 columns and 5 rows of data. Let's assume `file1`, `file2` and `file3` are in the same directory. What I want to do is to create an average file, which has the same format as `file1`/`file2`/`file3` where it should have the average of the each element from the table. For example,

```
{(Element in row 1, column 1 in file1)+
 (Element in row 1, column 1 in file2)+
 (Element in row 1, column 1 in file3)} >> 
(Element in row 1, column 1 in average file)
```

Likewise, I need to do it for each element in the table, the average file has the same number of elements as the `file1`, `file2`, `file3`.

I tried to write a shell script, but it doesn't work. What I want is to read the files in a loop and grep the same element from each file, add them and average them over the number of files and finally write to a similar file format. This is what I tried to write:

```
#!/bin/bash       
s=0
for i in {1..5..1} do
    for j in {1..4..1} do
        for f in m* do
            a=$(awk 'FNR == i {print $j}' $f)
            echo $a
            s=$s+$a
            echo $f
        done
        avg=$s/3
        echo $avg > output
    done
done
```

Comment: This needs a little more context. You call the files `file1`, `file2` in your description, but the scripts shows that they're called `m`something. Example input and output would help, too. Also, what's not working with your solution? (I mean, I can tell that getting `$j` into awk won't work like this, but what error do you get?)

Comment: I am sorry that was a mistake in my folder the files are having names m1,m2,m3. (not file1,file2,file3) that is why I have m* in the script. The FNR == i {print $j}' $f I added thinking about this 'FNR == 5 {print $3}' to print the 3rd field in the 5th line. The error is its not working in the loop as you mentioned. I was wondering the how to fulfill that requirement in a loop. And also my other problem was how to write the average in a similar way to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather inefficient way of going about it: for every single number you're trying to extract, you process one of the input files completely – even though you only have three files, you process 60!

Also, mixing Bash and awk in this way is a massive antipattern. [This here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) is a great Q&A explaining why.

A few more remarks:

- For brace expansion, the default step size is 1, so `{1..4..1}` is the same as `{1..4}`.
- Awk has no clue what `i` and `j` are. As far as it is concerned, those were never defined. If you *really* wanted to get your shell variables into awk, you could do

  ```
  a=$(awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" 'FNR == i { print $j }' $f)
  ```

  but the approach is not sound anyway.
- Shell arithmetic does not work like `s=$s+$a` or `avg=$s/3` – these are just concatenating strings. To have the shell do calculations for you, you'd need arithmetic expansion:

  ```
  s=$(( s + a ))
  ```

  or, a little shorter,

  ```
  (( s += a ))
  ```

  and

  ```
  avg=$(( s / 3 ))
  ```

  Notice that you don't need the `$` signs in an arithmetic context.
- `echo $avg > output` would print every number on a separate line, which is probably not what you want.
- Indentation matters! If not for the machine, then for human readers.

#### A Bash solution

This solves the problem using just Bash. It is hard coded to three files, but flexible in the number of lines and elements per line. There are no checks to make sure that the number of elements is the same for all lines and files.

Notice that Bash is *not* fast at that kind of thing and should only be used for small files, if at all. Also, is uses *integer arithmetic*, so the "average" of 3 and 4 would become 3.

I've added comments to explain what happens.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read a line from the first file into array arr1
while read -a arr1; do

    # Read a line from the second file at file descriptor 3 into array arr2
    read -a arr2 <&3

    # Read a line from the third file at file descriptor 4 into array arr3
    read -a arr3 <&4

    # Loop over elements
    for (( i = 0; i < ${#arr1[@]}; ++i )); do

        # Calculate average of element across files, assign to res array
        res[i]=$(( (arr1[i] + arr2[i] + arr3[i]) / 3 ))
    done

    # Print res array
    echo "${res[@]}"

# Read from files supplied as arguments
# Input for the second and third file is redirected to file descriptors 3 and 4
# to enable looping over multiple files concurrently
done < "$1" 3< "$2" 4< "$3"
```

This has to be called like

```
./bashsolution file1 file2 file3
```

and output can be redirected as desired.

#### An awk solution

This is a solution in pure awk. It's a bit more flexible in that it takes the average of however many files are supplied as arguments; it should also be faster than the Bash solution by about an order of magnitude.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Count number of files: increment on the first line of each new file
FNR == 1 { ++nfiles }

{
    # (Pseudo) 2D array summing up fields across files
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        values[FNR, i] += $i
    }
}

END {
    # Loop over lines of array with sums
    for (i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) {

        # Loop over fields of current line in array of sums
        for (j = 1; j <= NF; ++j) {

            # Build record with averages
            $j = values[i, j]/nfiles
        }
        print
    }
}
```

It has to be called like

```
./awksolution file1 file2 file3
```

and, as mentioned, there is no limit to the number of files to average over.

Comment: you can get rid of the line formatting if you change to `for(..) $j = values[i,j]/nfiles; print;` also better to leave the output file name out of the script.

Comment: @karakfa Ooooh, nice!

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I tried the awk solution you have shown and it worked fine for my files. If I want to improve this to a case where the file1, file2 file3 have some string in between how to select that specific columns with data? lets say column 1,2,3 and 5,7,9..has string columns and column 4,6,8,10 ..etc has the actual data in the original files. what I need to do is to change this for loop for (j = 1; j <= NF; ++j) right ?I used for (j = 4; j <= NF; j+= 2) to count through fields and I think it is working fine. Hope I am doing it right.

Comment: Thank you Karakfa!

Comment: @BenjaminW. How can this be modified for higher precision?

Comment: @thatWiseGuy There is a built-in variable that controls the precision of what `print` prints. You can have something like `BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%.10f" }` to increase precision; see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-CONVFMT-variable-1) for details.